# Horizontal line - Login Form

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a horizontal line aligned to the word "or" in this login form, however i can not get it to work as it will just align underneath the word.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/12byj.png

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box
}

body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Lato', Arial, sans-serif;
}

#loginForm {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="new 1.css">
</head>

<body>
  <form id="loginForm">
    <input type="text" class="login-username" placeholder="Username/E-mail" autofocus="true" required>
    <input type="password" class="login-password" placeholder="Password" required>
    <button type="submit" class="login-submit" name="submit">Login</button>
    <a id="forgotPass" href="#" class="login-forgot-pass">Forgot password?</a>
    <p>or</p>
    <a id="Signup" href="signup.html">Register</a>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an improvement of the old answer using less of code:

```css
.content {
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 200px;
}

.or {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(#000 0 0) left,
    linear-gradient(#000 0 0) right;
  background-size: 40% 1px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <p class="or">or</p>
</div>
```

**Old answer**

You may try before/after element like this :

```css
.content {
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 200px;
}

.or {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.or:before,
.or:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: " ";
  bottom: 10px;
  width: 40%;
  height: 1px;
  background: #000;
}
.or:after {
  right: 0;
}
.or:before {
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <p class="or">or</p>
</div>
```

Depending on the styles applied to your page you may change some values to get exactly what you need. You can change `bottom` value and `left` of after element and `right` of before element